# Custom UITableViewCell with reuseIdentifier without Style?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

In my tableview, I need a bunch (5-6 types) of different cells. All have the same visual layout for items, but content wise (label names, pictures and colors), they differ a lot.

So I have a CustomUITableViewCell base class, designed in Interface Builder with this common design. This CustomUITableViewCell class server as a base class for bunch of cell subclasses.
I generate these subclasses with a class method from a factory class using factory pattern.
These subclasses do not have xibs. Why would they, the have common design.

Now the problem is, for each subclass I need a different reuse identifier.So, one would think lets override the default initializer for each subclass, and in it, call another initializer, the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

The problem is it requires the style to specify. I can't put `nil` there, it complains. But I do not need any style from Apple, I have obviously my own style, why would I do the custom design if I wanted to have a stock style. I only need to specify the reuseIdentifier.

How to assign reuse identifier if it's readonly property and it seems that the only way to provide it is through the initializer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem some time ago. My solution was to re-declare `reuseIdentifier` as read-write property in the implementation file (of the `UITableViewCell` subclass)

```
@interface MyCustomCell ()
@property(nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString *reuseIdentifier;
@end
```

and to synthesize the property with a *different* instance variable:

```
@implementation MyCustomCell
@synthesize reuseIdentifier = _myCustomCellReuseIdentifier;
```

Now you can assign `self.reuseIdentifier` in the init method of your custom cell.

At least it worked in my case, perhaps you can use it ...

Comment: I managed to override that property (a neat trick btw. :) ), but for some reason, the queue does not return the cell instance the second  and subsequent times in cellForRow..even if the cellIdentifier matches for sure...it always goes in the if cycle to crete a new one.
AFAIK, I should not care to get the cell into queue, should I? It gets there by default after first datasource call, does it?

Comment: @Earl: I am not sure if I understand your last comment correctly, but cells are only reused when you scroll. If a cell is not needed anymore because the row is not visible anymore then the cell is reused for a different row.

Comment: Yes, I did not know that. So it works, i tried to scroll and it dequeues. Thank you.