# Setting .reuseIdentifier on a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, nib, uicollectionview

I have a particular `UICollectionViewCell` that I want to **instantiate myself**, and add to a `UICollectionView`. In order for this to work, the `UICollectionViewCell` instance needs its `.reuseIdentifier` property to be set.

Normally, the class or Nib that describes the cell is registered with the collection view, and the collection view instantiates the cell with its `.reuseIdentifier` already set, with these methods:

```
- registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
- registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
```

However, since I am constructing this cell outside of the collection view, these do not apply.

When I create the cell myself, there appears to be no way to set its `.reuseIdentifier` (because it is a readonly property, and there are no `init...` methods that initialize it).

When `.reuseIdentifier` is not set, the `UICollectionView` throws an exception when the cell is added. This behavior is different from `UITableView`, where reuse identifiers were optional.

An easy workaround to set the collection view cell's reuse identifier is to embed it in a `.xib` file and use the `Identifier` box, then create an instance of the cell with

```
[NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:@"MyCellName" owner:self options:nil][0];
```

I can then pass the above-instantiated `UICollectionViewCell` and everything works fine.

...but that seems like a pretty silly and arbitrary hoop to jump through. Is there some other way to get this property set on the cell instance without the `.xib`-wrapper detour?

---

Update: Apple's documentation says this:

> To simplify the creation process for your code, the collection view requires that you always dequeue views, rather than create them explicitly in your code.

...which is actually not true, because it doesn't require this (i.e., externally-instanced cells work fine as long as their identifier is set *somehow*, e.g. if loaded from a `.xib`), and it also doesn't "simplify the creation process for my code" in my particular use case (rather requires an extra file; further it would be messy to require that the collection view create these few complex one-offs).

But the above does seem to imply that the answer to the question is no: it's intentionally "difficult" to create a usable cell except by having the collection view dequeue it.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729612/custom-uitableviewcell-with-reuseidentifier-without-style/12730053#12730053. (It is for table view cells, but I think it should also for collection view cells.)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good trick to try. I was also wondering whether `setValue:forKey` "works around" the `readonly` bit. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to say it, but I think you're going to have to accept the fact that UICollectionView is the sole Apple-branded factory for producing UICollectionViewCells. So if you have two collection views in which you want to display the exact same *object*, you're out of luck!

The good news is that if you have two collection view in which you want to display a cell that *looks* exactly the same as in the other, then you can accomplish your task. It's easy:

```
@interface MyModelClass : NSObject
  // a bunch of data
@end


@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
-(void)refreshCellWithObject:(MyModelClass *)object;
@end
```

Meanwhile, in whichever classes own the UICollectionView cv1 and cv2

```
[[self cv1] registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionViewCell"];
```

and

```
[[self cv2] registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionViewCell"];
```

And their data sources can look the same

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MyModelObject *obj = [self theObjectIWant];

   MyCollectionViewCell *cell;

   cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   [cell refreshCellWithObject:obj];

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: "I think you're going to have to accept the fact that UICollectionView is the sole Apple-branded factory for producing UICollectionViewCells." But it is obviously possible to create UICollectionViewCells using a xib, without a UICollectionView.

Comment: You may be right, but earlier this year I decided to go with Apple's recommended practice after lengthy experimentation. See my somewhat-related Q&A at http://stackoverflow.com/q/15939234/1224741. It has a somewhat-related quote from an Apple engineer.

Comment: Could you provided the implementations of refreshCellWithObject: method? How it could refresh Cell with reuseidentifier.

Comment: That method is something you implement to fill in all the cell's views based on the given object.

Answer (score 2):

Use these two methods.

```
– registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
– dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```

See apple's [UICollectionView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: The above methods work as advertised, but this doesn't answer my question. What I'm doing here is passing in a few arbitrary one-off cells to a collection view which are being constructed elsewhere. Also, what I am asking is how to *avoid* using a .xib.

Comment: You want to construct a UICollectionViewCell use code and then use it at other place?

Comment: Correct, I want to call some sort of `init` method on a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and then display that specific instance in a collection view.

Comment: I've searched and I think you can only load it from a .xib file. Sorry about this.

Comment: I think there might be some tricks one can use to set the property directly; see the first comment on the question. But using a `.xib` seems the safest way.

Comment: @sunkehappy: This does not answer the question of why it's possible to set the reuse identifier when creating it from a xib, and not possible when creating it in code. In both cases, you are not dequeuing it.