# Am I required to call UICollectionView's dequeueCell: from within the data source's cellForPath:?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I really, really want to provide 'static' cells to my UICollectionView, ala the old days with UITableView. But I know that we good boys and girls must use `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` as a factory for our cells. So I propose the following scheme, and request feedback on its potential. So far, it is working for me, but I dread an unknown gotcha.

```
#import "MyCellClass.h"

@implementation MyViewController {
   MyCellClass *_cell0; // etc - many are possible. could store in array
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
   // assume MyCellClass has a +nib and +reuseId. The reader understands.
   [_collectionView registerNib:[MyCellClass nib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[MyCellClass reuseId]];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:animated {
   // this is where the fun begins. assume proper counts coming from the datasource
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithRow:0 inSection:0];
   _cell0 = [[self collectionView] dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[MyCellClass reuseId] forIndexPath:indexPath];
   // etc
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if ([indexPath row] == 0) return _cell0;
   // etc
}
```

I deliberately gloss over details such as configuring the cell. Madness? Genius? Just status quo? It seems to be working so far, but I fear that, somehow, Apple expects `dequeue` to be called from within `cellForPath`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the real answer is "you're not required to do it!"  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Response from the Apple TSI Guy:**

> Although you said your app works, you really should use
>   "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier" from within the data source
>   method "cellForItemAtIndexPath".  That is the supported use pattern. 
>   Don't try to hold on you MyCellClass, let the collection view manage
>   that and it will ask you to dequeue it if necessary.

I'm going to pout a little, change my code, and then issue an enhancement request. But I tell you it worked just fine!

Answer (score 4):

The only reason for calling `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is to reuse cells. But a "static" collection view? How many cells are we talking about? If I had a collection view small enough that it never scrolled, I would consider not bothering to reuse cells at all. *That* would certainly solve the problem neatly. After all, a static table from the storyboard isn't reusing cells; that is what makes it static. So I would say, drop the stuff about `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` altogether and just supply cells when asked.

There is nothing magical about `dequeue`; it's just a way of finding out whether there are any cells in the reuse pile, and getting one if so. After all, consider how table views worked in, say, iOS 4. You said `dequeue`, but if there were no reusable cells to give back, the table returned `nil` and you had to `alloc-init` your own cell or pull it out of a nib, *yourself*. Well, you are proposing to do that for *all* items in the collection view. Go right ahead.

Comment: I agree - we're talking about 6 cells, large, 4 to a page (horizontal scroll). For this one. I anticipate changes in the future. It's a little messy at the moment. I agree with you in principle, but the details of the situation demand something like this.

Comment: As for supplying cells, I thought I was *required* to dequeue them. Can I alloc/init/loadNib? I would rather do that anyway, in this case.

Comment: Absolutely. As I said in my answer, the only reason for dequeuing is to get them off a reuse pile. If you aren't reusing, you don't need to do that. And because you are dequeuing them all up front, you are already not reusing them.

Comment: See my revised extended all-singing all-dancing answer.

Comment: The docs insist that we must use dequeue. `Creating Cells and Supplementary Views` in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: That is one way of reading it. :) But I assure you that I would sooner not dequeue at all than dequeue outside the moment the datasource is being asked for the cell.

Comment: I will shortly be updating a project to prevent reuse of collection view cells (in my case the overhead of reconfiguring cells and the number of cells in the view doesn't make reuse sensible). I'll either be taking Matt's approach, or register a larger number of reuse identifiers, and use a different identifier per index path. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Code sample? I presume we would have to use loadNib, because UICollectionReusableView's reuseIdentifier is readonly?

Comment: I posted an answer to my question, but it's more or less the same as yours, so I'll give you the points. And I'll undo my downvote if you edit your answer (just add a space or something) :P

Comment: @jrturton how did it go?

Comment: @QED I did the latter - generated and registered multiple (I settled on 10) of reuse identifiers and tied them to the index path. It worked well and fits in with your reply from Apple.

Comment: Trying to init: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier'

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [MBStaticCollectionView](https://github.com/matibot/MBStaticCollectionView), it enables you to define static UICollectionView cells from the Interface Builder without the need to define a datasource.