# Add view controller to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have viewController that have fabric create methods, depending on specific integer. What i want is, to make collection view, with each cell is representing that controller.

> Problem is, UICollectionViewCell is a view, but I've ViewController.

What I tried is subclass UICollectionViewCell like follow (paste that code in subclass of UICollectionViewCell):

```
 CalendarViewController *vc = [CalendarViewController create];
    UIView *vw =  vc.view;
    [self addSubview:vw];

   [vw mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

       make.left.top.right.bottom.equalTo(self);

   }];
```

Last line is simply added constraints.

Now I've 2 problems:

1. It treated like a view, and i cant click on specific areas (cells, CalendarViewController is collection view also)
2. Sometimes view vanish and there is only blank view on a screen.

Answer (score -1):

View controller in UICollectionViewCell is a tricky situation as it is respective view controller's responsibility to handle views touches. You can refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384799/4209778) for some approaches.

But, this situation when UICollectionViewCell  needs to be a UIViewController is handled here: https://github.com/zats/Voltron, if you can use third party code: