# Programmatically made UICollectionViewController not showing cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

The background is **black** and the cells are **white** though none of the cells are showing in the `simulator?` would any one know why this might be?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ChatLog: UICollectionViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)    
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.height, height: 80)
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try debugging?

Comment: You probably did not set the `class` in storyboard.

Comment: If you're using a xib cell:  collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "nibname", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "reusableCellID")

Comment: In `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` you are getting an error as you are setting the width of the cell to be the views height. Replace with `return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 80)` I presume.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:**

Initialising the ChatLog view controller programmatically as follows means that the UICollectionView datasource methods aren't called e.g `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` isn't called.

`let newViewController = ChatLog(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())`

Replace with **this**:

`let newViewController = ChatLog(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())`

--

As you have declared a `UICollectionViewController`, you don't actually need to set explicitly in code, the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of your collection view.

Simply make sure that in the `Main.storyboard`, you have set the class of your `UICollectionViewController` to ChatLog by clicking on the view controller and then the identity inspector. Also ensure that you have clicked the `UICollectionViewCell` and set it's Identifier to "cellId".

If this is a multiple view controller project, ensure that it is possible to navigate to ChatLog view controller by making it initial view controller or providing segue/navigation to this view controller from another view controller.

Pictures below outline my solution.

[image: Storyboard Cell]

[image: Storyboard UICollectionViewController ChatLog]

Comment: how are you initialising and navigating to the collection view controller? Can you edit the question to include this info?

Comment: @bennypalmer661 check this out if you're using xibs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281631/setting-reuseidentifier-on-a-uicollectionviewcell

Comment: i am not using xibs and i dont think it has anything to do with how i am gettting to the chatlog collectioviewcontroller i think the problem now is that cell for item is not being called?

Comment: @bennypalmer661 I have updated my answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: i put let newViewController = ChatLog(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()) above view did load and it gave an error BAD ACCESS"

Comment: Where have you added this line? I am unable to reproduce your issue. Usually you'd have to call the `present(newViewController, animated: false)` as well and be sure to write this after `viewDidAppear` or anywhere after the Initial View Controller is loaded into the window hierarchy (i.e not in viewDidLoad). Usually bad access means you have forced unwrapping somewhere. But it's difficult for me to help without more information about your code.

Comment: @bennypalmer661could you please share how you are invoking ChatLog viewcontroller?

Comment: Wow the `UICollectionViewLayout` vs `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `delegate` and datasource of the `collectionView`. The `datasource` and `delegate` methods(`numberOfItemsInSection`, `cellForItemAtIndexpath`, etc) will be called only if you have set the `delegate` and `datasource`. You can set it either in code or in storyboard(if you have used storyboard to design the `collectionView`)

In the `viewDidLoad` you can add

```
 collectionView.delegate = self
 collectionView.datasource = self
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this though it has not made any difference

Comment: @bennypalmer661 does the cellForItemAtIndexpath and numberOfItemsInSection is getting called?
Where have you added the collevtionView to the view ?

Comment: numberOfItemsInSection  is called though cell for Item is not being called?

Comment: @bennypalmer661 where have you set the frames of the collectionView ?

Comment: @  Aravind A R    in    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.height, height: 80)
    }?  i still can't figure this out been on it for days

Comment: @bennypalmer661 actually when I tried your code I'm able to see the collectionView with 5 white cells
Could you please share how are you invoking the ChatLog viewController