# Disable cell reuse on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionView in my app with gesture recognizers on the individual cells which allow the user to "slide open" the cell to reveal more data underneath.

The problem is, I am reloading the data in the CollectionView very often; as the app receives updates once every 3 seconds or so. This results in unwanted behavior with the collectionview cells being reused while a cell is in the process of being slid.

The user will start to slide a cell, the app will receive an update, reloadData, and a different cell will start receiving the gesture instead, and begin sliding.

I have tried disabling the app's updates while the slide is occurring, but that caused other complications within the app, so I am wondering if there is a way to disable the cell reuse, (I will only have 20 cells max, so I don't think there would be a large drop in performance).

Thank you!

Comment: Are you just calling reloadData? What happens if you just reload specific cells, e.g. all those except the one that is being operated on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a flag like `needsReload` and set it, if new data is available. After a slide you check for that flag and reload the collectionView, if needed? Is this not working?

If you don't want cell reusing, just use a default scrollView and put all your views in it!?

Answer (score -5):

Disabling reuse is simple.  Just don't use the dequeueReusableCell method.
Instead just alloc, init your cells.  I would be careful of the performance and memory implications of doing so though...

Comment: I tried that, I filled an array with however many cells I needed, and in cellForRowAtIndexPath I put:
`MyCustomCell *cell=[self.arrayOfCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`


But the app crashes with the following error. 

`*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:]`

Comment: `*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UICollectionView.m:1138`

Comment: @dKrawczyk: How do you create the collection view cells? Using a nib file or purely in code? - Perhaps this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281631/setting-reuseidentifier-on-a-uicollectionviewcell and my workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729612/custom-uitableviewcell-with-reuseidentifier-without-style/12730053#12730053 helps.

Comment: Why are you not doing something like:  MyCustomCell *cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] init]; ???  You are trying to access the cells in the collection view before there are any cells in it.  The whole idea of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is that it populates the view.

Comment: Be sure to mark an answer as correct if it solves your problem.

Comment: the "self.arrayOfCells" is an array of cells that have been initialized, but I have tried your way as well and it still gives the assertion failure that I posted above.

Comment: @HackyStack have you tried that? can you confirm that it is possible?